# Printing 2 things from a list twice then printing next 2 things twice (loop)

Tags: python

I'm new to coding and I'm trying to make a program that will take 2 vegetables from a list and print them one after another, then go to the next one and print it again. So if I have something like this:

```
vegetables = { "tomato": "red", "cucumber": "green", "orange":"orange", "lemon": "yellow" }
```

How do I make it say in console:

```
"tomato": "red", "cucumber": "green"
```

and after that

```
"orange":"orange", "lemon": "yellow"
```

And if it's possible can it say `"tomato": "red", "cucumber": "green"` twice and after that `"orange":"orange", "lemon": "yellow"` twice again. And I would love if it worked for many elements because I will have bigger list.

Comment: So what have you tried so far? Please update your question with a snippet of code that you tried and did not work as expected.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the most "pythonic" way to iterate over a list in chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks) Where the *list* is `vegetables.items()`

Answer (score -1):

A dictionary is organised with keys/values:

```
my_dictionnay = { my_key : myvalue }
```

(You can add any keys/values as long as his keys are different.)

So you can use `keys()` & `values()` methods on the `vegetables` dictionary.

Those methods returns each keys and values from your dictionary.

Example: get each `values` from your dictionary:

```py
vegetables = { "tomato": "red", "cucumber": "green", "orange":"orange", "lemon": "yellow" }

for colour in vegetables.values():
    print(colour)
```

You can do the same for the keys changing `vegetables.values()` to `vegetables.keys()`

Now let's get our keys/values in a single for loop;

```py
vegetables = { "tomato": "red", "cucumber": "green", "orange":"orange", "lemon": "yellow" }

for vegetable, colour in vegetables.items():
    print(vegetable, ":", colour)
```

If you want more details on dictionary you can read [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_ref_dictionary.asp).

Comment: 1. This doesn't answer the question, which is how to print in chunks of 2 elements. 2. Why `zip(d.keys(), d.values()` when `d.items()` exists?

Comment: Also you do `for vegetable, colour in ...:` but then `print(key, ':', value)`. Both `key` and `value` are not defined...